# How to find runtime of other c programs

Tags: c++, c, time

I want to find the time taken by another program to run ;
I am using following code;

```
system("time ./a.out > garb");
```

it is giving very weird output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

        long int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ ) {
                printf("Hello World!\n");
        }
        printf("C Program\n");
        return 0;
}
```

output

```
0.31user 0.10system 0:00.41elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1744maxresident)k
0inputs+253912outputs (0major+149minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: Looks like GNU time to me. What did you expect? POSIX format?

Comment: I want to calculate the time that the above program to run using a c/c++ program.
For that i am running system("time ./a.out").
but this isnt giving the output as it gives when we run it through bash.

Comment: That's because there is a version of `time` built into bash, while in your code you call a program installed in your system (GNU time). bash's version outputs in POSIX format by default, while GNU time outputs a different format. You can make it output in POSIX format with `time -p` in your code. Why don't you try what User1 suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `wait3` or `wait4` functions (if those are available in your system).

```
pid_t wait3(int *status, int options, struct rusage *rusage);    
pid_t wait4(pid_t pid, int *status, int options, struct rusage *rusage);
```

Your program will get resource usage of a child process after the child is exited.

All fields of `struct rusage` are not updated, but the first two fields tells what you want:

```
struct rusage {
    struct timeval ru_utime; /* user CPU time used */
    struct timeval ru_stime; /* system CPU time used */
    ...
```

Sum of `ru_utime` and `ru_stime` is the total CPU time used by the child process.

Using of `wait3 / wait4` is not so simple as calling of `system()` function.

EDIT:
You should get same result by summing those two values of printout of `time`:

> 0.31user 0.10system

Comment: can you give some advice how to calculate the runtime of other c programs in an easier way by a c program

Comment: @Shubham Sharma : Maybe it is easier to use the system() function as you did. And parse times from the text. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

i think we can found another way instead of `time` in system.
Something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    system('./a.out');
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: This just measures wall time, not e.g. if time is spent in user code or waiting for some system resource. Not sure that's what OP wanted since the question is incomplete.

Comment: Yes but he wants something different than "time ./a.out" and the post contains  the tags `c`.

Comment: anyway can you please tell me what did you mean by wall time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is difficult to get accurate results using C's library functions or system calls. Instead, it is better to use Performance API ([PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/)) for more accurate results. To be more specific, you can see this [function](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/docs/d2/d16/classPAPI__get__real__cyc.html) defined by PAPI.